# How to configure subdomains with Payara and virtual servers?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, glassfish, payara

I'm struggling here with something that may be easy to do, but I haven't found a correct solution, so i hope you can help me please.

## Background

We are developing an application that consists in 4 different Java Web projects.

1. AppA
2. AppB
3. AppC
4. WebService

All of these applications have to be accessed from 4 diferent sub domains of **mydomain.com**:

1. a.mydomain.com
2. b.mydomain.com
3. c.mydomain.com
4. api.mydomain.com

## Technology

Application server: Payara server 4 (what is almost the same that Glassfish 4).

Payara server is running inside a Docker container which in turn is running inside an Amazon EC2 instance.

I've used Amazon Route 53 in the following scenario:

## What I have already done successfully

This was done for another proyect where there was only 1 app which is accessed from a subdomain of **otherdomainiown.com**.

This works perfectly, because the DNS records of the domain provider ([iPage](http://ipage.com)) just points to my Amazon Route 53 records of the hosted zone I configured. This hosted zone has an A record that points to the fixed IP of my Amazon EC2 instance. Then, Docker exposes Payara server through port 80 that is [mapped](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/) to port 8080 which Payara uses by default to serve it's applications. 
[image]

## Problem

Now, i'm facing a similar scenario. The difference is that I have 4 different apps that need to be accessed by 4 different sub domains.

I've tried with Virtual Servers (virtual hosts) with no luck, I'm not familiar with that, but i think that could be a possible solution.

I considered using Amazon S3 buckets to redirect but I don't think that's what I need.

In an image, this should be the final scenario, although I just draw 2 sub domains for simplicity:

[image]

- Should I use Docker mappings to resolve this?
- Should I use Virtual Servers?
- Should I buy 4 different machines? (this will solve all this in a few seconds, but buying more instances is not an option)
- Should I use a Docker container for each application?

As you can see, i'm a little lost, so it would be great if you could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using Route 53 for? What benefit do you get from it in this scenario?

[There is a blog post on the Payara website which gives an overview of using Virtual Servers in Payara Server, but it's a bit in-depth to quote for an answer here](https://blog.payara.fish/virtual-servers-in-payara-server).

The key point is that you still need to configure incoming traffic to ***arrive*** at different subdomains. If all your traffic is coming in on the same IP address as it looks like Route53 is doing, then it will be very tricky to differentiate what traffic should go to which endpoint.

The usual way to do this would be to have a load balancer or proxy where you have Route53 in your diagram. An Amazon ELB would be able to perform the redirects you need. A cheaper option (though it would involve more management) would be to use something like Apache httpd or Nginx to forward requests to the Payara Server.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a virtual server for each subdomain and set the subdomain in the "Hosts" field. Then you need to dpeloy all 4 applications and select the proper virtual server in the "Virtual Servers" field. The blog linked by @Mike will guide you: https://blog.payara.fish/virtual-servers-in-payara-server

All of the virtual servers will be listening on the same IP address but Payara Server will read the domain from incoming HTTP requests and will route the request to the correct virtual server.

However, this is recommended only for very small applications. Bigger applications should be deployed separately on different Payara Server instances running on different ports or different machines. If you use docker then you can run 4 instances in docker and map them to different ports. Then you would need a proxy server (Apache Httpd, Nginx, ) to route requests to the correct Payara instances (ports) according to the domain name in requests.